# Pass more attributes in the select2 generated element

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I use select2 library as below:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single;" id="countries_list" name=""></select>


countries_list = [];
for (var property in datamap.options.data) {
     countries_list.push(datamap.options.data[property]['country']);
}
$("#countries_list").select2({
   data: countries_list.sort(),
 });
```

This works fine but what I need is also to pass inside the  some other attributes as well. For example the name parameter. How can I do that with select2?

Comment: why do want to pass name parameter?

Comment: I need to pass name parameter or any other attribute. I will retrieve this attribute later to use it in one function

Comment: so you are looking to set the name to each options in dropdown as value attribute

Comment: yes. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your set the `countries_list` values in a format of id and text as `inputdata` data in the following solution you can achieve this.

[image: Output]

```js
var inputdata = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'enhancement'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'bug'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'duplicate'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'invalid'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: 'wontfix'
    }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
       tags: "true",
       placeholder: "Pick one",
       allowClear: true,
       data: inputdata 
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" >
</select>
```